# How to reset items in select from dropwdown itself

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, antd

I want to clear/remove/reset select options from dropdown itself and not from **external button** or `allowClear`

Let's say the icon of a trash in select option will reset all values:

[image]

However, I'm quite stuck on how to reset the value with this my current following code:

```js
import st from "./AddToCartDropdown.module.css";
import {useState} from 'react';

import { Select } from 'antd';
import { DeleteFilled } from '@ant-design/icons';

const { Option } = Select;

function loopStock(n, selectedIndex){

    var elements = [];
    for(let i = 1; i <= n; i++){
      const qty = new String(i);
      const resultQty = qty.concat(" in cart");
      elements.push(<Option value={i}> <span className={st.addToCartSelect}> {i === selectedIndex ? resultQty : i} </span></Option>);
    }
    return elements;
}

const AddToCart = () => {
  const [selectedIndex, setSelectedIndex] = useState(-1);
  const onChange = (newSelectedIndex) => {
    setSelectedIndex(newSelectedIndex);
  }
  
    return (
      <div >
        <Select defaultValue="Add to Cart" onChange={onChange} className={st.addToCartDefault} bordered={false}>
          <Option value="delete"> <DeleteFilled /> </Option>
          {loopStock(5, selectedIndex)}
        </Select>
    
      </div>
    );
  };
  
  export default AddToCart;
```

When I select the trash icon, it supposed to show me `Add to Cart` instead of trash icon:
[image]

The problem is I'm confused how to set the state after I selected the icon of trash in order to reset all options and go back to `Add to Cart` default value of `Select`.

I'm new to React/JavaScript and still learning. After searching all solutions, I think it's the best to create my own question in here. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make your select as a `controlled` component by passing a value prop and having a state. set the initial state to `null` instead of `-1` so that we can use the placeholder.

```
const [selectedIndex, setSelectedIndex] = React.useState(null);
```

when the selected value is `delete` we are setting the state to `null`

```
const onChange = (newSelectedIndex) => {
    if(newSelectedIndex === 'delete'){
      setSelectedIndex(null)
    }else {
      setSelectedIndex(newSelectedIndex)
    }
  }
```

Now add the `value` and `placeholder` prop in your select.

```
<Select placeholder="Add to Cart" value={selectedIndex} onChange={onChange}  bordered={false}>
          <Option value="delete"> <DeleteFilled /> </Option>
          {loopStock(5, selectedIndex)}
</Select>
```